# Full witdh and height in react-native (and GiftedChat specifically)

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am trying `GiftedChat` ('react-native-gifted-chat' package)

My code is:

```js
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{width:400}}>
      Welcome to React Native! {check()}
    </Text>
    <GiftedChat
      style={styles.welcome}
      messages={this.state.messages}
      onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
  </View>

const styles:any = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
})
```

[image: GiftedChat]

Why the Gifted chat component is not fully visible? What am I doing wrong? What do i need to do to fit it on full available screen width and height? What do I need to try to check?

Any suggestions very appreciated.

Comment: show `styles.welcome`

Comment: I try to set {width:400} for that styles or not specify at all. This did not change the view. I found solution by return GiftedChat not wrapped. If some one found how to solve with wrapper as in original code please write one more answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it worked if return `GiftedChat` component with no wrapped containers instead of:

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{width:400}}>
      Welcome to React Native! {check()}
    </Text>
    <GiftedChat
      messages={this.state.messages}
      onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
  </View>
)
```

write:

```js
return (
  <GiftedChat
    messages={this.state.messages}
    onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
    user={{
      _id: 1,
    }}
  />
)
```

Comment: Lol this actually solved the same problem for me that I've been struggling to fix for the past few hours... Doesn't make any sense...